# JQuery stop an automatic function and set interval to restart

Tags: jquery, setinterval

The following function triggers some slides to move automatically.

```
function featloop(eq){
        if(eq == $('.featuredslider a').length) { return false }
        else {
            $(".featuredslider a").mouseleave();
            $('.featuredslider a:eq(' + eq + ')').mouseenter();
            var next = eq + 1;
            window.setTimeout(function(){featloop(next);}, 3000);
        }
}
```

However if the user happens to trigger the mouse enter function as well then this automatic function needs to stop, an interval needs to be triggered so that if the user executed mouseleave() then the automatic function starts from the beginning again in 8000 ms. Is that possible, and how.

Comment: when it should be stop ? mouse enter where? can you give more information and also can you share html?

Comment: I guess the easiest way would be binding the mouseenter event - inside the binding - create a binding to mouselive and calling the featloop with another variable - that would replace the 3000 with 8000 (changing the function appropriatly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean somethink like:

```
function featloop(eq,ms){
        if(eq == $('.featuredslider a').length) { return false }
        else {
            $(".featuredslider a").mouseleave();
            $('.featuredslider a:eq(' + eq + ')').mouseenter();
            var next = eq + 1;
            if (!ms){ms=3000);
            window.setTimeout(function(){featloop(next);}, 8000);
        }
}

$('$featureslider a').bind('mouseenter',function(){//or whatever your selector
    $('featureslider a).bind('mouseleave',featloop(eq,8000)); //I know this isn't the right call for eq, but I don't understand the original binding and html. so fix it properly
}) ;
```